# How can I retrieve the Full COM-Port name as displayed in the device manager?

Tags: windows, registry

Every other Windows update junks the COM-Port list and the new COM-Port Numbers need to be matched up.
Already have a script in place to ping all the current ports - see what it returns and assign accordingly.

Issue is certain Bluetooth devices create a COM-Port and if Filemaker (Clients platform) tries to ping said port, crashes.

[image: However all Bluetooth devices appear as Standard Serial Over Bluetooth link]

Is there anyway I can pull this information out as a txt file or similar so I can avoid pinging Bluetooth devices? I have a feeling this can be done through Command Prompt just havnt found it

I have mucked around with editing the registry through scripts in the past, and I know the location of the COM ports.

Just need to export out from
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter\Devices

Answer (score 2):

Type this in a command prompt:

```
wmic path Win32_SerialPort get caption, name, deviceID
```

So you would be able to identify each COM port (friendly name), and the associated device. I have only one COM, with the same string for both `caption` and `name`, so you may probably remove one of the two in the command line.

It can also be done programmatically by using Win32 API, if needed.

Comment: This does get me out of trouble. Any reason why it only returns only Standard Serial and over Bluetooth and not USB Serial Port devices?

Comment: @Nic Simply because USB isn't a COM port... USB is indeed a serial bus, but it's not a _serial port_, exactly like PCIe (serial bus too) isn't a serial port either. You can't plug a serial device on your USB like this, you'll need to enumerate the device, use the USB protocol, and _THEN_ you could use it as you want: serial port, audio card, mouse input, mass storage, ... so you'll need to enumerate these devices to find your USB devices. USB ports themselves can be obtained with `wmic portconnector where "PortType=16" get ExternalReferenceDesignator, InternalReferenceDesignator`.

Comment: @Nic But to find a particular USB device, you must check for what it IS... A pendrive? Check for `Win32_LogicalDisk`. A mouse? Check for `MSMouse_PortInformation`. A set of speakers? Check for `Win32_SoundDevice`. And so on... And if you have an USB serial port adapter, _THEN_ you'll find it under `Win32_SerialPort`. [This page](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmiqueries.php) gives basics about WMI classes.

Comment: Cheers for the clarity - FTDI (FTDICHIP) is installed on the computers, so the port names appear in the device manager in a similar way. As I said above, the main part was eliminating out of all the ports Filemaker receives which are the BT so it can ignore those ports. I'll look more into the other commands in-case some bright spark try's to change everything in a few months